# Checking for a "winner" before the game is finished

Tags: java, android

My code works with an if statement that counts until 10 moves are made and then checks who the winner is in getWinner() but, that is an issue when somebody wins before all 10 moves are made.

I originally had just the getWinner(); method with no if statement assuming this would check for a winner every time a button is clicked. This did not give me any errors but it simply did not work properly.

What else can I try? Why does just adding the getWinner(); without the if statement not work?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public int counter = 1;

private Button button1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

//This repeats for all buttons, I left it all out for the sake of making the post shorter.

```
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()    {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (button1.getText().toString().equals("")) {

                    if (counter % 2 == 0) {
                        button1.setText("O");
                    } else {
                        button1.setText("X");
                    }
                    counter++;
                }
                if (counter == 10)  {
                    getWinner();
                }
            }
        });

//add the other buttons here...

public void getWinner() {
String b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9;

b1 = button1.getText().toString();
// code here
  }
```

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is far too much code here.  In order to make it clear exactly where your problem is, please remove any code that is not directly causing your problem, and if you can reduce it to ten lines or less, I will consider retracting the downvote.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am not receiving an error so I don't know where it is. Not sure if its logic or placing a method in wrong place. I have messed around with the code for a while now. I broke it up but since that's not good enough for you go ahead and keep your downvote.

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger. Remove the if statement, put a breakpoint in your getWinner() function after you've assigned the strings, and examine the contents of each of the variables.

Comment: Also, "it simply did not work" is not a useful problem statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like none of the buttons aside from button1 matters:

```
b1 = button1.getText().toString();
b2 = button1.getText().toString();
b3 = button1.getText().toString();
b4 = button1.getText().toString();
b5 = button1.getText().toString();
b6 = button1.getText().toString();
b7 = button1.getText().toString();
b8 = button1.getText().toString();
b9 = button1.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment: "I originally had just the GetWinner(); method with no if statement assuming this would check for a winner every time a button is clicked. This did not give me any errors but it simply did not work properly."

Assuming the code was not being executed as you expected when you attempted the above. I would suggest making a callback to GetWinner() every time the button is clicked.

Comment: I deleted more code to shorten post but another user caught it beforehand, i  made and accidental error when copying and pasting making only button one matter.

Answer (score 0):

With all the Strings getting their value from the first button did it work if you clicked the first button?

Comment: Without the if statement the program ran as expected to which was weird, without the if statement only when the first button was clicked it worked. I lacked details in post my apologies.